# function does not take 4 arguments

Tags: visual-c++, build, error-handling, atl

While building a project , I am seeing an error message like
:ReadFromStream' : function does not take 4 arguments
Can you please suggest me what could be the error.

Below is the line , it is showing the error exits:

```
hr = var.ReadFromStream(pStm, pMap[i].vt, pMap[i].rgclsidAllowed, pMap[i].cclsidAllowed);
```

I would appreciate any help .Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you using and what compiler?

Comment: Read the documentation about ReadFromStream... Maybe it really doesn't take 4 arguments

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition of the function, usually this occurs when you are missing a parameter (or have one too many)

If it is supposed to take four of them, make sure one of your parameters isn't the wrong type for the overload you are attempting to use.  Sometimes that can make it think you are trying to use a different overload that doesn't use that number.

Answer (score 1):

> :ReadFromStream' : function does not
>   take 4 arguments Can you please
>   suggest me what could be the error.

That means that **ReadFromStream** doesn't take 4 arguments.

That means you can't pass 4 objects into it.

**(pStm, pMap[i].vt, pMap[i].rgclsidAllowed, pMap[i].cclsidAllowed)**

pStm

Map[i].vt

pMap[i].rgclsidAllowed

pMap[i].cclsidAllowed

Answer (score 0):

I think in the definition of ReadFromStream, the method does not have 4 parameters as arguments. Please revisit that.

Answer (score 0):

[Related bug on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/214357/error-in-comcli-h)